# Convert Python function to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a user-defined function in Python in my Snowflake db to parse specific JSON key.

```
create or replace function get_tag(tag_json string, tag_key STRING)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('json5')
HANDLER = 'get_tag_py'
AS
$$
import json
def get_tag_py(json_data, key):
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    value = data.get(key)
    return value
$$;
```

It works as expected but the performance is quite slow. I converted the function to JavaScript as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  get_tag_js(json_data string, key string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var json_data, key;
var parsedData = JSON.parse(json_data);
value = parsedData[key];
return value;
$$
;
```

It fails at runtime with the following error:

```
select get_tag_js(json_column, 'MY_KEY') from my_orders_tbl;
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON in GET_TAG_JS at 'undefined' position 0
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't define `json_data` as a `var`. It is already a parameter of your stored function. By declaring it with `var`, the parameter becomes unreachable, and instead you have an undefined variable.

Comment: I don't know "snowflake" at all, but my intuition tells me you have redefined `json_data` and thus it has an undefined value.

Comment: Why do you think Javascript will be faster?  Both have to be interpreted on the fly.

Comment: @JonSG that's correct. Every time it is called, which is why it is slow.

Comment: In my day we were taught about normalization of databases. Nowadays... JSON. This is what you get.

Comment: @trincot I declared `json_data` as a `var` because db throws a `JavaScript execution error: json_data is not defined` error at runtime if I don't.

Comment: If it works like in Python, shouldn't you define a function in the JS part? ... A function that takes two parameters?

Comment: @trincot I just realized my mistake. Will update my post with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to your Question:

Your function should not declare the same named parameters, this is why the are undefined. Also the docs state the parameters will be UPPER CASE, because that is how all tokens are treated in SQL, thus in your JavaScript they need to be upper case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  get_tag_js(json_data string, key string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);
    value = parsedData[KEY];
    return value;
$$
;
```

and now we can use those

```
select get_tag_js(json_column, 'MY_KEY') 
from values 
  ('{"key1":"value1", "MY_KEY":1235}'),
  ('{"key1":"value1", "my_key":22356}')
    as t(json_column)
;
```

[image]

If you really want lower case parameters in the function (that should not exist as shown (but this could be a toy example)) then use quotes to force them to lower case like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  get_tag_js("json_data" string, "key" string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(json_data);
    value = parsedData[key];
    return value;
$$
;
```

Case insensitive, can be achieved by pulling the object apart and doing a case insensitive match. Which is more likely still faster than the exact same steps in JavaScript/Python

```
select 
    get_tag_js(json_column, 'MY_KEY') as r1
    ,GET(PARSE_JSON(json_column), 'MY_KEY') as r2
    ,GET_PATH(PARSE_JSON(json_column), 'MY_KEY') as r3
    ,f.value as r4
from values 
('{"key1":"value1", "MY_KEY":1235}'),
('{"key1":"value1", "my_key":22356}')
as t(json_column)
cross join table(flatten(input=>PARSE_JSON(json_column))) as f
where f.key ilike 'MY_KEY'
```

[image]

Comment: How do you handle a scenario when the key can be upper-case, lower-case or mixed case? Is there a native function in Snowflake allowing parsing of a key regardless of case i.e. "KEY", "key", "keY" will return a match regardless of the case???

Comment: fair point, thus the "toy example comment". I would tend to "to lower" the other object string then. myself, seems JSON is case sensitive, `{"key1":1, "KEY1":2}` is valid, so "case matters there,.,,

Comment: the flatten method does not allow for a left join like behavior

Comment: I have several hundred millions of records to parse.  It takes 315 ms for my javascript UDF run over 6100 rows. That's the performance I need.

Comment: @CB you note 6,100 rows takes 315ms, are you meaning you want ~300ms for the 100M rows, or the 0.05 ms per row is fine? Aka 5M seconds performance is fine by you??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a UDF to parse JSON in Snowflake. For simple JSON, you may query the key directly

```sql
select json_column:MY_KEY from my_orders_tbl
```

For more complex JSON, you may need to use FLATTEN. See [Querying Semi-structured Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the “var json_ data, key;” line and made “json_data” and “key” parameters in the function definition and everywhere else in upper case letters only.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tag_js(json_data string, key string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS '
  // Define a function 
  function get_tag(JSON_DATA, KEY) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);
    value = parsedData[KEY];
    return value;
  }

  // Now call the function that we defined earlier.
  return get_tag(JSON_DATA, KEY);
  ';
```

It works as expected. Now I need to mod it to take a key regardless of case.